# Django template blocks

Tags: django, django-templates

I currently have...

```
<title>
MyApp | {% block customtitle %}{% endblock %}
</title>
```

What I want really is for the `|` to **only** appear if the `customtitle` block is NOT empty. I only want to see `MyApp` in the title if the page does not set the customtitle block.

Is that an option? How would one implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much simpler to define your base template like this:

```
<title>
{% block customtitle %}MyApp {% endblock %}
</title>
```

then in your derived templates

```
{% block customtitle %}
{{ block.super }} | Custom Title
{% endblock %}
```

The presence of block.super will ensure that MyApp will appear in all the pages. Using block.super instead of hard coding MyApp will ensure that changing the base template in the future will not break the title.

Comment: I take your point about hardcoding `MyApp`. I was only planning on setting it in the base template. It would just be super elegant not to have to put the `  |  ` in every derived template too. And it would allow that format to also be changeable in the base template instead of editing all derived templates should the need ever arise.

Comment: that cannot be done beause the base template doesn't have information about the derived templates.